# Can't remove White background behind facebook buttons

Tags: css, facebook, internet-explorer-8

I am seeing a weird issue. I am seeing white background behind facebook share/link buttons at this website http://goo.gl/pR8S0 for IE8 only. In other browsers it seems fine. I can not determine where it is getting the white background from. There should be no white background. Rather I need it to be blueish #00AEEF background color. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Use allowtransparency="true" for IE to behave more nicely like other browsers and the problem gets solved for IE8. As it is solved for IE8, I can hopefully guess that it is solved for IE9 also.